# Retrieve multiple images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve multiple / single images from DB using jquery. as per the way I tried, I am receiving only the first image. The rest are not visible.

For saving multiple images I am using comma after to separate. EX: saved 2 imaged named x.jpg and y.jpg, The image name will be saved in the column as x.jpg,y.jpg and image will be uploaded to the folder.

```
var image_DB = data[0].pimage; //FROM DB COLUMN
var upload_dir = "../uploads/"; //IMAGE PATH
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.height = 90;
img.weight = 90;
                    
if(image_DB !== ''){ //IF IMAGE COLUMN HAS A VALUE || IMAGE
   if(image_DB.includes(',') !== false){ //IF THE COLUMN CONTAINTS MULTIPLE IMAGES
      console.log('Multiple Images Here');
      var image = image_DB.split(',');//SPLITTING IT WITH COMMA -1
      $.each(image, function(key, value){ //ITERATING VALUES TO FIND FILE NAME
           img.src = upload_dir+value; //UPDATING IMAGE SOURCE
      });
    }else{//IF THE COLUMN CONTAINTS ONE IMAGE WITHOUT COMMA
       console.log('Single Image Here');
       img.src = upload_dir+image_DB;
    }
}else{ //IF NO IMAGE EXISTS
   console.log('Nothing is in DB');
}
$('#preview').prepend(img);
```

Where am I making the mistake? Please suggest.

The way its done in PHP is

```
if($row['pimage'] !== ''){
   if(strpos($upload_dir.$row['pimage'],',')!== false){
        $image = explode(',',$row['pimage']);
        $imageArr = '';
        foreach ($image as $im){
           $imageArr .= '<img src="'.$upload_dir.$im .'"width="150" height="150"/>';
        }
   }
   else{
       $imageArr = '<img src="'.$upload_dir.$row['pimage'].'"width="150" height="150"/>';
   } 
}else{
   $noImage = 'No Image.jpg';
   $imageArr = '<img src="'.$upload_dir.$noImage.'"width="150" height="150"/>';
}
```

Comment: If there are multiple images in your database, you will need to create a seprate `img` tag for each of them. What happens now is that you create one image, and change it's `src` attribute multiple times, this will naturally only lead to one image being displayed.

Comment: why cant we loop through one img tag? I have achieved this in PHP and now I am rewriting it on Jquery.

Comment: HTML and PHP are completely different things. In HTML the `img` tag represents one single image. You can of course change the `src` attribute dynamically which will cause the image to change as well. But you can not have multiple images showing at the same time with only one `img` tag.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. I have edited the question to show how it is done in PHP using html tags.

Comment: Your php `foreach` creates a new element for each instance. The `.=` keeps adding to the html string every iteration

Comment: okay @Smurker I was just confused with img tag and img variable. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one `img` object and you assign it multiple images, so only one will be displayed

```
var image_DB = data[0].pimage; //FROM DB COLUMN
var upload_dir = "../uploads/"; //IMAGE PATH
                    
if(image_DB !== ''){ //IF IMAGE COLUMN HAS A VALUE || IMAGE
   if(image_DB.includes(',') !== false){ //IF THE COLUMN CONTAINTS MULTIPLE IMAGES
      console.log('Multiple Images Here');
      var image = image_DB.split(',');//SPLITTING IT WITH COMMA -1
      $.each(image, function(key, value){ //ITERATING VALUES TO FIND FILE NAME
           var img = document.createElement("IMG");
           img.height = 90;
           img.weight = 90;
           img.src = upload_dir+value; //UPDATING IMAGE SOURCE
           $('#preview').prepend(img);
      });
    }else{//IF THE COLUMN CONTAINTS ONE IMAGE WITHOUT COMMA
       console.log('Single Image Here');
       var img = document.createElement("IMG");
       img.height = 90;
       img.weight = 90;
       img.src = upload_dir+image_DB;
       $('#preview').prepend(img);
    }
}else{ //IF NO IMAGE EXISTS
   console.log('Nothing is in DB');
}
```

Here you have example of multiple images added.